# mysql select or join from two tables issues error

Tags: mysql

i have two tables named t1 and t2.

t1 have 500 rows and t2 have 220000 rows. the relationship between these tables are t1.t_id and t2.t1_t_id. not all t1 rows have corresponding row in t2.
now this line of code works fine

```
SELECT t1.t_id , t2.t1_t_id FROM t1, t2 
where  t2.t1_t_id = t1.t_id and t1.t_id=11
```

but this does not work

```
SELECT t1.t_id , t2.t1_t_id FROM t1, t2 
where  t2.t1_t_id = t1.t_id
```

[image: error is:]

in case picture not available

error is:
1 error were found during analysis 
1. missing expression (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query edit
set foreign_key_checks=on
mysql said

## 2006 server has gone away

what i want to do after solving this issue is: 
t1 have a column named p_id which is primary.
i recently added a new column in t2 named t1_p_id.

now i want to update t2.t1_p_id = t1.p_id where t2.t1_t_id = t1.t_id.

i know i should use inner join on t2.t1_t_id = t1.t_id in a update query but it also issues the same error.

my guess for the error is that i should specify some specific condition because not all t1 have corresponding row in t2

**update**
i am querying by browser by mysql console

thanks

Comment: please do not say why you want to do so when you already have connections between the tables: reason is that connection t1.t_id was a big mistake i have doen!! :(

Comment: In the second query you are using archaic join syntax, but still you do have a join condition.  It looks like MySQL is dying for some reason.

Comment: @Tim how can i found that reason!